# Angular Font Awesome in a component library - FontAwesome: Could not find icon with iconName=times and prefix=fas

Tags: angular, font-awesome-5

I have an Angular 7 component library that uses FontAwesome icons.

First of all, output of `ng version`:

```
Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.10.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.10.7
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.10.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.10.7
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.10.7
@angular-devkit/core               7.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics         7.0.7
@angular/cdk                       7.1.1
@angular/cli                       7.0.7
@angular/compiler-cli              7.0.4
@angular/language-service          7.0.4
@angular/material                  7.1.1
@ngtools/json-schema               1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                   7.0.7
@schematics/angular                7.0.7
@schematics/update                 0.10.7
ng-packagr                         4.4.5
rxjs                               6.3.3
typescript                         3.1.3
webpack                            4.19.1
```

And relevant tidbits in `package.json`:

```
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.8",
"@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.5.0",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.5.0",
```

Here's my module definition:

```
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';

import { faAngleDown } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faAngleDown';
import { faBars } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faBars';
import { faCalendarAlt } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faCalendarAlt';
import { faCaretLeft } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faCaretLeft';
import { faChevronDown } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faChevronDown';
import { faSortUp } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faSortUp';
import { faSortDown } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faSortDown';
import { faChevronUp } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faChevronUp';
import { faChevronLeft } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faChevronLeft';
import { faTimes } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faTimes';
import { faUser } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faUser';
import { faSignOutAlt } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faSignOutAlt';
import { faQuestionCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faQuestionCircle';
import { faGlobeAmericas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faGlobeAmericas';

<app imports>

library.add(
    faAngleDown, faBars, faCalendarAlt, faCaretLeft, faChevronDown,
    faChevronLeft, faChevronUp, faGlobeAmericas, faQuestionCircle, 
    faSignOutAlt, faSortDown, faSortUp, faTimes, faUser
);

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        <app components>
    ],
    exports: [
        <app components>
    ],
    imports: [
        FontAwesomeModule,
        <other app imports>
    ]
})
export class LibModule {
    public static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: LibModule,
            providers: [
                <some providers>
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

Here's `public_api.ts`:

```
export * from './lib/lib.module';
<component exports>
```

I can build this module with `ng build mylib --prod` just fine. However, when I try to use it in an application, whenever the `--prod` flag is used to build or serve, I get the following errors:

`FontAwesome: Could not find icon with iconName=times and prefix=fas`

Here's the `app.module.ts` file for the application:

```
import { faCalendarAlt } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { LibModule } from 'libmodule';

<app imports>

library.add(faCalendarAlt);

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        FontAwesomeModule,
        LibModule.forRoot(),
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

`app.component.ts` is using the `faCalendarIcon`, and also bringing in components from `LibModule` which in turn are using the icons described in the lib module definition.

The calendar icon displays just fine when using `ng serve --prod` or `ng build --prod` and then serving the application not through the baked angular dev server. However, every icon used by the library components themselves don't show up, and I see the error from the title in the console for every one of them.

Please note that this doesn't happen when I use `ng serve` without the prod flag, so it may have something to do with tree-shaking?

How can I use FontAwesomeModule within a library and make sure that the consumers of the library can see the icons as well? I'd rather not have to make all consumers import all icons used by the library.

Note that I'm using deep imports with my FontAwesome icons, I've also tried to do "shallow" imports as such:

```
import {
  faAngleDown,
  faBars,
  faCalendarAlt,
  faCaretLeft,
  faChevronDown,
  faChevronLeft,
  faChevronUp,
  faGlobeAmericas,
  faQuestionCircle,
  faSignOutAlt,
  faSortDown,
  faSortUp,
  faTimes,
  faUser
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
```

I've also tried for my lib module to export FontAwesomeModule, and not to export it. I've tried exporting each icon, but that's not possible it seems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, we figured it out internally.

In the library, the `library.add(...)` statements that were just floating in the library module definition file need to move to the module constructor. This solves the issue.

Comment: I'm having the same issue even though the ```library.addIconPacks()``` are inside the constructor of my AppModule.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option.

1. Create a new project `ng new ng-fontawesome`
2. Create a new library in the project `ng generate library ng-fa`
3. Install font-awesome packages `npm install --save @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons`
4. Update `projects/ng-fa/src/lib/ng-fa.module.ts` to import/export the fontawesome module

   ```
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
   import { NgFaComponent } from './ng-fa.component';
   import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

   @NgModule({
     declarations: [NgFaComponent],
     imports: [FontAwesomeModule],
     exports: [NgFaComponent, FontAwesomeModule]
   })
   export class NgFaModule { }
   ```
5. Update `projects/ng-fa/src/lib/ng-fa.component.ts` to utilize a fontawesome icon

   ```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   // import { IconDefinition } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types';
   import { faAddressBook } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';
   @Component({
     selector: 'lib-ng-fa',
     template: `
       <fa-icon [icon]="icon"></fa-icon>
     `,
     styles: []
   })
   export class NgFaComponent {
     // icon: IconDefinition = faAddressBook;
     icon = faAddressBook;
   }
   ```
6. Update `src/app/app.module.ts` to import your library module by name(not relative path)

   ```
   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
   import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
   import { NgFaModule } from 'ng-fa';

   @NgModule({
     declarations: [
       AppComponent
     ],
     imports: [
       BrowserModule, NgFaModule
     ],
     providers: [],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })
   export class AppModule { }
   ```
7. Add npm scripts to cause the library to be built before the application is. In the `scripts` tag in the main `package.json` file I added to entries.

   - `"build:ng-fa": "ng build ng-fa"`
   - `"prestart": "npm run build:ng-fa"`

I tested this with the start command but you would need to do the same thing for your build command.

I then ran `npm run start`(dev) and `npm run start -- --prod` to test both builds and they are working fine. This greatly reduces the need for all of the imports as you are doing it above. Here you only need to import the icons in the components that actually need them(not in the module as well).

I have created a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/PdUi/stack-overflow-answer-repos/tree/master/ng-fontawesome) with this sample as well.

Comment: how is this better than just using the normal <fa-icon [icon]="['fas','faSearch']"></fa-icon>?
I could see it being handy if the icons where more dynamically set where you don't need to declare them.

Comment: @nonoandy https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/f91fa200463e908111a9fa48214a8d0cd7face37/docs/usage/explicit-reference.md

Answer (score 0):

Using `library` from `@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core` to import icons didn't work for me, I would still get the error. Instead, I used `FaIconLibrary` from `@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome` like this:

```
import { FaIconLibrary, FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { faStore } from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons';

export class YourModule {
  constructor(library: FaIconLibrary) {
      library.addIcons(faStore);
  }
}
```

Now if I use in my template the following:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="['fal', 'store']"></fa-icon>
```

It works with no issue.